# Phonegap Application does not Start

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phone gap, I am confused why my application does not starts.

My code for html and log cat is shown below.

When i run application, it shows me a blank page.

INdex.html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

                <!--<link href="css/HDFCERGO_CSM.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                 <link href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
                <link href="css/Custom-HDFC.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/jquery.mobile.custom-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->

                <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


                <link href="css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <script src="scripts/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

                <script src="scripts/lib/jquery.mobile-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/lib/iscroll.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/backbone-validation-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/jquery.md5.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/backbone.validation.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/utility/MessageUtils.js"></script>

    <!-- Utility
     <script src="scripts/utility/AJAX.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/utility/ajax-config.js"></script>
     -->
    <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/utility/router.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/utility/common.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/utility/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/utility/oauth.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/utility/OAuthUtils.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/application.js"></script>

    <!-- Model JS -->
    <script src="scripts/models/AuthenticationModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/UserModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/CashTransactionModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/BasiscontractModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/FuturescontractModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/HTAcontractModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/IndemnitypaymentModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/OptionscontractModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/OtherRevenueModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/PercentagecontractModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/CommonFetchServiceModel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/AccountSummaryModel.js"></script>



    <!-- Views JS -->
    <script src="scripts/views/LoginView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/HomeView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/CashTransactionView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/BasiscontractView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/FuturescontractView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/HTAcontractView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/IndemnitypaymentView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/OptionscontractView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/OtherRevenueView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/PercentagecontractView.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/views/LeftsideMenu.js"></script>


    <!-- nativeDroid: Color Schemes --
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.color.yellow.css" id='jQMnDColor' />
    <!-- nativeDroid core CSS --
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css" />
    lem. I have user entered data that my app save daily in sqlite and updates the values. I have developed a Custom
    <!-- nativeDroid: Light/Dark --
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.dark.css"  id='jQMnDTheme' />

     -->



    <title>HDFC ERGO LOGIN PAGE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

//        function isOnline(){
//            
//            
////            var _check=true;
////            var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
////            var states = {};
////            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
////            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
////            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
////            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
////            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
////            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
////            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
////            
////            if(networkState==="unknown" || networkState==="none")
////            {
////                
////                _check=false;
////                // showAlert();
////                return _check;
////            }
////            else
////            {
////                
////                return true;
////            }
//
//}
            // return (navigator.network.connection.type !== 'none' && navigator.network.connection.type !== 'unknown') ? true : false;
       // }

        function isTextInput(node) {
            return ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1;
        }

    document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
          if (!isTextInput(e.target) && isTextInput(document.activeElement)) {
              document.activeElement.blur();

              var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
              for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
              inputs[i].blur();
              }

          }

        }, false);

        $.support.cors = true;
        $.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;

        var myScroll;

        function imageUpload() {
            $('#firstImage').attr("src", "images/hdfc.png");
        }

        $(document).on('pageshow', function () {
            $('#inputPasscode').val("");
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#btnSyncClaimDetail', function () {
            syncClaimDetails();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#btnPasscode', function () {
                      // showLoading();
        jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery('#homepage'), { transition: "flip" });


            //validatePassCode();
                       //alert("rohit");

//                       appAvailability.check(
//                                             'fb://', // URI Scheme
//                                             function() {  // Success callback
//                                             alert("rohit1");
//                                             },
//                                             function() {  // Error callback
//                                             alert("rohit2");
//                                             }
//                                             );
//                       
//                       appAvailability.checkBool('fb://', function(availability) {
//                                                 // availability is either true or false
//                                                 if(availability) { alert("rohit1");}
//                                                 });

        });
        /* Calendar Event Clear Function */
        $(document).on('click', '#event-clear', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            clearCalendarEvent();
        });

        /* Calendar Event Save Function */
        $(document).on('click', '#event-save', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            saveEventToCalendar(event);
        });

        $(document).on('keypress', '#inputPasscode', function () {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                validatePassCode();
            }
        });


        $(document).delegate("#viewHistoryImages", "pageinit", function () {
            $('.swipebox').swipebox({
                useCSS: true,
                useSVG: false,
                hideBarsOnMobile: false,
                hideBarsDelay: 3000,
                videoMaxWidth: 1140
            });
        });

        $(document).delegate("#viewBreakInImages", "pageinit", function () {
            $('.swipebox').swipebox({
                useCSS: true,
                useSVG: false,
                hideBarsOnMobile: false,
                hideBarsDelay: 3000,
                videoMaxWidth: 1140
            });
        });

        function openClaimScreenlist() {
            jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery('#claim-screen-list'), { transition: "none" });
        }
        $(document).on('click', '#btn-save-claimNo', function () {
            alert('save');
            openClaimScreenlist();

        });
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#newCalendar', function () {
            $("#container .iscroll-content").html("");
            var pageName = 'calendar';
            $.get("./pages/" + pageName + ".html", function (html) {
                $("#container .iscroll-content").html(html);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.mobile.activePage.trigger("create");
                    $("#container").iscrollview("refresh");
                    setCalendarHTML();
                }, 500);
            });

        });

        $(document).on('pageshow', '#dashboardpage', function () {
            /*changes for Panel Dashboard*/
            $('.ui-panel').css({ 'top': 59 });
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#ss").click(function () {
                $("#st-container").addClass("st-effect-11");
                $("#st-container").addClass("st-menu-open");
                $("#ss").hide();
                $("#closeb").show();
            });

        });

        // Open DropDown

        $(document).on('click', '#dd', function (event) {

                       $('.ClickList').css("background","white");

                       $(this).toggleClass('active');

                       event.stopPropagation();
        });



        // Close DropDown

       $(document).on('click', '.ClickList', function (event) {


                    //  jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery('#CashTransactionScreen'), { transition: "slide" });
                      $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");
                      $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');

                      $(this).toggleClass('active');

                      event.stopPropagation();


        });

        // Chnage Password

        $(document).on('click', '#ChangePasscode', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#OptionRightMenu').panel().panel('close');

        });

        // SignOut

        $(document).on('click', '#signout', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#OptionRightMenu').panel().panel('close');

                       jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery('#passcode'), { transition: "flip" });


        });

        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_CashForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#CashTransactionScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

        // CashTransactionScreen1

       $(document).on('click', '#CashTransactionScreen1', function (event) {

                      // Close DropDown

                      jQuery('#CashTransactionScreen').panel().panel('open');


                      });


        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_HTAForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#HTAcontractScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // HTAcontractScreen1

                       $(document).on('click', '#HTAcontractScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#HTAcontractScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });



        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_BasisForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#BasiscontractScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Basis contract

                       $(document).on('click', '#BasiscontractScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#BasiscontractScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });


        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_PercentageForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#PercentagecontractScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Percentage contract

                       $(document).on('click', '#PercentagecontractScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#PercentagecontractScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });


        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_FuturesForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#FuturescontractScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Futures contract

                       $(document).on('click', '#FuturescontractScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#FuturescontractScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });


        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_OptionsForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#OptionscontractScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Options contract

                       $(document).on('click', '#OptionscontractScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#OptionscontractScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });


        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_IndemnityForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#IndemnitypaymentScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Indemnity payment

                       $(document).on('click', '#IndemnitypaymentScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#IndemnitypaymentScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });

        // Back_CashForm

        $(document).on('click', '#Back_OtherForm', function (event) {

                       // Close DropDown

                       jQuery('#OtherRevenueScreen').panel().panel('close');


                       });

                       // Options contract

                       $(document).on('click', '#OtherRevenueScreen1', function (event) {

                                      // Close DropDown

                                      jQuery('#OtherRevenueScreen').panel().panel('open');


                                      });



// Menu List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList', function (event) {

    $('.ClickMenuList').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu1 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList1', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList1').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList1').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu2 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList2', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList2').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList2').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu3 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList3', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList3').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList3').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu4 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList4', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList4').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList4').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});



// Menu5 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList5', function (event) {

    $('.ClickMenuList5').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList5').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu6 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList6', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList6').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList6').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});

// Menu7 List click

$(document).on('click', '.ClickMenuList7', function (event) {


    $('.ClickMenuList7').css("color","white");
    $('.ClickMenuList7').css("background","Transparent");


    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).css("background","rgb(234, 201, 44)");


});





    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <!-- LoginScreen Start data-iscroll --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


   <!-- LoginScreen End  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


    <!-- HomeScreen Start  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->



<!-- HomeScreen End  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->




  </body>
</html>
```

And Log Cat is:-

```
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991): Error loading url gap://ready
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=gap://ready }
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.startActivityForResult(DroidGap.java:1107)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(CordovaWebViewClient.java:149)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:293)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:96)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-07 02:39:12.393: E/Cordova(1991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Both Code and Data is shown.Please if any one is having an idea then please show me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create the phonegap project?

Comment: what is the name of base html file `INdex.html` or `index.html` ?

Comment: Seems your AndroidManifest.xml is somehow broken. What version of cordova are you using? And as already asked how did you create the project?

Comment: I have create android project in eclipse, and then add Cordova file and create WWW folder in it.

Comment: File Name is index.html

Comment: Seems you're doing it the old way (pre cordova 3). For cordova 3.x you should use the cordova CLI to create your project and add the android platform (as described in Max's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a problem with your AndroidManifest ("No Activity found..."). Be sure to follow the documentation (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and start again from the beginning.

`$> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$> cordova platform add android`

copy your files into the www folder (replace index.html with your file content)
then try to run

$> cordova run`